# How do I make someone an administrator in VSO?

Tags: azure-devops

I need to set someone as having full administrative rights to do anything in VSO. Where/how do I set this?

Comment: have you seen https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/add-account-users-assign-access-levels-team-services ?

Comment: @OlegBogdanov - yep, have that set to unlimited. But still that person can't add users.

Comment: @DavidThielen Can you add another user to your VSTS after you add that person to project collection administrators group?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Sorry, no. Tried everything and failed. However, we're moving over to Git (because get latest is flaky on TFS) and so not an issue for us anymore. thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

After you add a user to your VSTS, you also need to [add it to project collection administrators group](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/add-account-users-assign-access-levels-team-services#permissions), after that he can add users to VSTS too.

1. Go to admin page (https://XXX.visualstudio.com/_admin/_security)
2. Select Project Collection Administrators
3. Click Members tab
4. Click Add button to add user to Project Collection Administrators group